# Comparar JSONArray y la hora actual del servidor

Tags: android, android-studio

Cordial saludo,

Tengo una base de datos Mysql y paso el valor de una columna llamada hora a un JSONArray, mi problema es que no se como comparar si la hora en base de datos es mayor a la hora en el servidor de base de datos.

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
ja.getString(3) ---> Este es el arreglo que tiene la hora almacenada en base de datos
```

Y deseo compararla asi, aunque se que no es la forma:

```
if (ja.getString(3) >= Time()) { }...
```

Comment: ¿La hora del JSON es la de la BD? ¿Qué formato tiene la hora del JSON?

Comment: Gracias por preguntar, HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que quieres comparar solamente la hora, nada más, lo cual complica el asunto en vez de facilitarlo :)

Entonces:

```
java.util.Date date= new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date); 
// obtienes cada elemento por separado de la fecha y hora actual 
int horas = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutos = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int segundos = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

// Los unes en una cadena
String sActual = horas + "" + minutos + "" + segundos;

//Cadena de tu array, limpiada de los :
String sArray=ja.getString(3).replace(':', '');

//Conviertes a entero los dos valores que quieres comparar
int nActual = Integer.parseInt(sActual);
int nArray = Integer.parseInt(sArray);

// Comparas:

if (nArray >= nActual) { }...
```

Comment: Gracias, una ultima  como utilizo este codigo para convertir el Array de JSON a minutos, por ejemplo si tiene valor de 03:10 convertir 190 minutos

Comment: Si ves en el código, la hora es calculada aparte: `int horas = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);` Si una hora tiene 60 minutos, multiplicas la variable `horas * 60` por ejemplo `int nTotalHoras=horas * 60;` y le sumas los minutos, que también has calculado por separado en el código: `int nTodoMinutos=nTotalHoras+minutos;` En el caso del ejemplo sería: 3x60=180 y 180+10=190  :)

Comment: Me ha sido muy util tu ayuda.